# Android - Location by LocationManager different from GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, locationmanager

I have created a location listener by 'LocationManager' with this code:

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 100, mListenerNetwork);
```

and the listener:

```
LocationListener mListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // New Location by LocationManager
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)  { }
}
```

And I have a listener by google maps API:

```
getMap().setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
```

and the listener:

```
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
    // New Location by GoogleMaps       
}
```

When I debugged the application, I have noticed that the locations in the listeners are different! More than that, the accuracy of the location are **very** different. The accuracy in the Google Maps is half of the accuracy in LocationManager (less is better).
Why the locations are so different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely GoogleMaps is using new `LocationClient` API, which was announced on Google I/O 2013. You may want to switch to this API too.

It is said to be more accurate and use less battery.

More info on how to get location updates: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that this class exists. Can I set provider to this? for example to listen to network provider only, or GPS only, or both?

Comment: @Someone No. The provider there is called "fused" and it uses one or more real providers, merging the data from them.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to requestLocationUpdates is only requesting location updates from the Network Location Provider (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).  The Network Location Provider uses cell tower and WiFi signals to determine location.  There is also a GPS Location Provider (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) which uses GPS satellites and is far more accurate when satellites are available.  Google Maps is most likely using a combination of the two location providers to determine the most accurate position.

Take a look at this guide for some more insight into the best way to utilize Android's location services for your needs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html